new React Native project not starting on android simulator
i'm getting this error, this is new RN project using 'npx react-native@latest init' with the initial template:
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an 
exception. * What went wrong: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Instagram Clone\Frontend\instagramclone\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-8246c9d0-6550-4e4b-9954-43caf3cc7c98) to immutable location 
(C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Instagram Clone\Frontend\instagramclone\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a) > Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Instagram Clone\Frontend\instagramclone\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-8246c9d0-6550-4e4b-9954-43caf3cc7c98) to immutable location (C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Instagram Clone\Frontend\instagramclone\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a) * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 4s.

since this is literally a brand new project i haven't touched anything yet just tried to run it as soon as it was created.

you can remove the spaces between the path
Personal Instagram Clone
to
PersonalInstagramClone
and then try
exception. * What went wrong: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\PersonalInstagramClone\Frontend\instagramclone\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-8246c9d0-6550-4e4b-9954-43caf3cc7c98) to immutable location

The solution was to downgrade gradle version through android studio to 8.5 from 8.6. Then upgrade back
